# Chrome autocomplete on secure HTTPS pages

Tags: google-chrome

Chrome won't save my form username on password on secure HTTPS sites. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [*Autocomplete = on*](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ecpgkdflcnofdbbkiggklcfmgbnbabhh) extension.

Comment: Did you test it? Does it actually work for HTTPS pages? All it does is flag the password element to include autocomplete, but if Chrome treats HTTPS pages specially, then it wouldn’t/shouldn’t make a difference.

Comment: I now think Chrome doesn't treat secure HTTPS any differently, and it was simply the HTML form autocomplete attribute frustrating me. That extension solved my problem.

Comment: Great.​​​​​​​​​